# Using validation set in training model after adjust hyperparameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm doing my best with creating model for imbalanced data using NN. I have a separate test set but I have a problem with validation data. Can I add validation data to train set after adjusting hyperparameters? Or it's better to leave this out and train final model only on the train data set? What do you think and what's your experience with this kind of data?

Answer (score -1):

The validation dataset is only for keras to calculate you a score for each epoch. So your model is not affected by this dataset, but you will get better statistics.

That means: You can set the validatedata set after you adjusted the hyperparameters and if you don't want to, you don't have to set validation data.

Comment: Okay, so after setting epoch and other stuff it's better to retrain it on all data?